# How to Close Delisted company's short position?

Tags: stocks, trading, stock-markets, stock-exchanges

I have shorted **OZON** and **YNDX** last year in **FEB** before suspending trading and after suspending was not able to close these positions. As Companies now are in delisted mode, Broker is not giving chance to close positions and giving bunch of reasons as they are suspended because of war and etc. I`m still paying each month fee for all these margin.

**IBKR**'s answer is following:

> Please note that delisting of ADRs does not mean that they cease to exist. The sponsor bank will deliver the Russian securities represented by the receipt or liquidate the stocks and allocate the proceeds to clients once it is possible and at own discretion of the sponsor bank. IBKR cannot affect this process.

Could u suggest ways to solve the problem, close positions somehow or get rid of it? or suggest someone who can help with that

Comment: If these are on margin, you likely need to add cash to your account first. That will close the margin position. As for removing a defunct security from your portfolio, well, I still have two of my early days trades from 15 years ago sitting in my account. I called once to get them removed, since they are literally nothing now, but they're still there. I kind of like them as a reminder. A token that I'm only human.

Comment: It sounds like this is up to the sponsor bank. Maybe find out who that is and what they are planning to do. Note that you did not short Russian companies, you shorted ADRs of Russian companies. The ADRs are now shutting down but you get an equal number of shares on the Russian stock exchange - or you would if you were long. No idea what they do with shorts.